# SQL Update that Updates rows as it goes. So nothing is used Twice.

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

this one is hard to ask, but I tried to search and couldn't find an example.

I have two tables:
For every row in the first table "TableA", there should be a matching row in the second table "TableB".   The "TableA" will have a foreign key that points to it's matching record in "TableB".

I need to update "TableA" and populate this foreign key, based on certain criteria..  The problem is more than one record in the "TableB" could match, but I don't want to use any of the records in "TableB" more than once.

**So once I've matched one of the records in the second table I never want to use it again.

I made this work, by looping "TableA" one record at a time, making my update, and making sure in my criteria that I don't use a record from "TableB" if it is already referenced in "TableA".

However, THIS IS SLOW.
Is there some way to do this in a single update statement?
Let me know if you need an example, I can probably fake something.

Comment: The reason it is slow is because you using a loop for updates. Yes some example tables and sample data are needed here. You will need to create this as a set based operation instead of RBAR.

Comment: An example would probably help us help you.

Comment: I think your wording is off.  More than one record in the TableB could NOT match if it is a proper FK relationship.  Then you have this problem of so you have multiple in TableA - which do you update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you have multiple rows with the same id in both tables.  What you need is a better join key.  And `row_number()` gives you that flexibility.  Here is what the structure of the code would look like:

```
with toupdate as (
      select a.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from a
     )
update toupdate
    set cola = b.colb
    from a join
         (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
          from b
         ) b
         on a.id = b.id and a.seqnum = b.seqnum;
```

Comment: If TableB is the FK table then ID should not repeat.  The question is not clear on that.

Comment: Gordon,  thank you for your answer.  I figured out what was going on above and in a simpler case I think it would have done what I needed.  Unfortunately there are multiple fields which make my records unique, and the sequence numbers don't particularly match up between my two tables, there are often times when my matching transaction doesn't even exist in the other table.   However, thanks to your example, I learned how row_number and partitions work.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes TableB is FK table with unique ID (PK)
And hopefully you have an order by that has a preferred row to update

```
with toupdate as 
(  select TableA.*, row_number() over (partition by FKb order by FKb) as seqnum
     from TableA
)
update toupdate
   set toupdate.cola = b.colb
  from toupdate 
  join TabeleB as b
    on toupdate.FKb = b.id 
   and toupdate.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I apologize my wording was bad.  There is no foreign key relationship currently.  That's more or less what I am setting up.  These are actually financial transactions that are matched by dollars/shares dates etc..  The matching is very imperfect.  This is why it's quite possible to find more than one record in table B that could match,  but I want the relationship to be one-to-one.

Comment: For your question to be of value to others you should clean it up and add sample data.  The answer from Gordon may be what you are looking for.